# Schiff Equation in a polar orbit

Tags: general-relativity, orbital-motion

I am aware that the formula for [Schiff Equation](http://www.google.com/search?as_q=Schiff+Equation) in used to determine frame-dragging is:
$$\boldsymbol{\Omega} = \frac{GI}{c^2r^3}\left( \frac{3(\boldsymbol{\omega}\cdot \boldsymbol{r})\boldsymbol{r}}{r^2}-\boldsymbol{\omega} \right).$$

But why does this reduce to: $$\boldsymbol{\Omega} = \frac{GI\boldsymbol{\omega}}{c^2r^3}\frac{\int_0^{2\pi}(3\cos^2\theta - 1)\text{d}\theta}{\int_0^{2\pi}\text{d}\theta} = \frac{GI\boldsymbol{\omega}}{2c^2r^3}$$ in a polar orbit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The angular velocity of the Earth $\boldsymbol{\omega}$ is oriented in the $z$-direction, so
$$
\boldsymbol{\omega} =(0,0,\omega).
$$
For a circular polar orbit we can chose the $x$-axis such that the satellite moves in the $xz$-plane. Therefore, the position of the satellite is
$$
\boldsymbol{r} = (r\sin\theta,0,r\cos\theta),
$$
and the frame-dragging vector can be written as
$$
\boldsymbol{\Omega}(\theta) = \frac{GI}{c^2r^3}\left(3\omega\sin\theta\cos\theta,\ \ 0,\ \ 3\omega\cos^2\theta - \omega\right)
$$
The **average** frame-dragging over one revolution is thus
$$
\boldsymbol{\Omega}_\text{av} = \frac{\int_0^{2\pi}\boldsymbol{\Omega}(\theta)\,\text{d}\theta}{\int_0^{2\pi}\,\text{d}\theta}.
$$
We get
$$
\Omega_{\text{av},x} = \frac{GI\omega}{c^2r^3}\frac{\int_0^{2\pi}
3\sin\theta\cos\theta\,\text{d}\theta}{\int_0^{2\pi}\,\text{d}\theta}=0,
$$
and
$$
\Omega_{\text{av},z} = \frac{GI\omega}{c^2r^3}\frac{\int_0^{2\pi}
(3\cos^2\theta -1)\,\text{d}\theta}{\int_0^{2\pi}\,\text{d}\theta} =
\frac{GI\omega}{c^2r^3}\frac{\pi}{2\pi}.
$$