# Does the frame dragging Schiff Equation imply opposite directions of spin over the pole compared to the equator?

Tags: general-relativity, frame-dragging

In reviewing the answers to [Schiff Equation in a polar orbit](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/96400/schiff-equation-in-a-polar-orbit), I see that the Schiff Equation for rotation about the z-axis (north-south pole axis) can be written as:

[image]

This is integrated to give an average rotation about the z-axis which is positive.  However, looking at the equation, it looks like a positive rotation at the equator where the angle is zero and the cosine term is 1, but a negative rotation at the pole where the cosine term is zero.  Am I correct to conclude that an object hovering over the equator will have a tendency to rotate in the same direction as the Earth while one above the north pole will rotate in an opposite direction to the Earth?

I ask because the analogy of an object spinning in honey is often used for frame dragging (or the phrase that a rotating body "drags space time" about it) but this equation seems to imply that analogy only works in the equatorial plane, and the opposite of "dragging" occurs whenever the cosine term squared is less than 1/3.